# Spring Boot repository with Example, Specification and Pageable together

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to make a complex pagitable filter in the repository.
I have succeeded, using Example and Pageable extending from:

```
extends JpaRepository <Card, Long>
```

Which in turn extends from:

```
extends PagingAndSortingRepository <T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor <T>
```

Right now the call is this:

```
Page<Card> findByCreatedDateBetween (Example<Card> exampleCard, Pageable pageable);
```

**PROBLEM**: I need to search by a date, which must be between two given dates. In `Example<Card>` it is not possible to indicate a range.

I have thought to do it with Specification, but I don't know how to make a call with the 3 parameters:

```
Page<Card> findByCreatedDateBetween (Specification<Card> cardSpecification, Example<Card> exampleOffer, Pageable pageable);
```

The same is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use both an `Example` and a `Specification` in one query, since `QueryByExampleExecutor` doesn't provide such a method.

You can also look at `SimpleJpaRepository` if you're interested in the implementation of `QueryByExampleExecutor`. Internally the implementation creates a `Specification` from the `Example`, using `QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder`. You may be able to use that to build your own `Specification` from an `Example` using that and then combine that `Specification` with another one.

The `ExampleSpecification` in `SimpleJpaRepository` is private, so you cannot use that, but you could copy it, and then do something like

```
findAll(ExampleSpecification(yourExample, escapeCharacter).and(yourDateRangeSpecification), pageable);
```